# JavaFX How do you convert coordinates (relative to the screen) to coordinates (relative to a pane)?

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, scrollpane

I'm going the coordinates of my cursor from Java.AWT.MouseInfo and I need to convert it to the coordinate relative to a ScrollPane's viewport. I'm trying to have the scrollpane's scrollbar positions center on where the mouse was when zooming in/out.

viewScroll is a ScrollPane. zoomGroup is a Group containing an imageView that is scaled (zooming). When scaled the method repositions the scrollbars where it was before the scale. I want to reposition the scrollbars where the mouse was at the time of zooming.

```
protected void zoom(double scaleValue) {
    p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    double Y = p.getX();
    double X = p.getY();

    double scrollH = viewScroll.getHvalue();
    double scrollV = viewScroll.getVvalue();

    zoomGroup.setScaleX(scaleValue);
    zoomGroup.setScaleY(scaleValue);

    viewScroll.setHvalue(Y);
    viewScroll.setVvalue(X);
}
```

Comment: Maybe [`Panel#screenToLocal(Point2D)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#screenToLocal-javafx.geometry.Point2D-) or [`Panel#ScreenToLocal(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#screenToLocal-double-double-) or [`Panel#screenToLocal(Bounds)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#screenToLocal-javafx.geometry.Bounds-)?

Comment: Based on your description, I really don't think `MouseInfo` is the best choice and maybe using something like `Node#getOnMouseMoved` and registering a `EventObject` with would be a better choice.  Don't really use FX, but even I think your approach is "dirty"

Comment: I need to get it local to the viewport I think. Not sure how to do that. As far setting an eventhandler on the ScrollPane, I have a filter set to disable scrolling by mouse wheel (filter for ScrollEvents set on the ScrollPane's parent) so it can only pan.

Comment: So, you're not filtering the other mouse events though?

Comment: Wouldn't getOnMouseMoved require the mouse be moving?

Comment: Yeah, that's my point, you could use something like `mouseMove` or `mouseClicked` to generate the events for your, which would (if I understand the API) give you localized events. If you're only filtering out wheel events, then it shouldn't effect the others (but I don't use FX, so I'm only assuming)

Comment: But I only want it to move the scrollbars when I zoom via Scrollwheel

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood, buy why should that stop from using mouseMove or mouseClicked?

Comment: Why would I use those, then I'd have the scrollbars moving around when I don't want them to.

Comment: Well, mouseMove just tells you when the mouse is moved within you're view, it doesn't effect the scrollbars, equally neither does mouseClicked (unless your clicking the scrollbsrs, but that's not where I'd be adding them)